# Passy password generator with boolean parameters

Tags: java, passwords, parameter-passing

Wanted to know the best way to solve this.
Input: Will be using the passayPassGenerator and setting the booleans.

Question: want to return the password string based on the booleans set from the wrapper function call

The problem by using if else/switch is the sheer number of combinations to deal with

```
private String passayPassGenerator(int len, boolean uppr, boolean lowr, boolean num, boolean spec) {
    CharacterRule upperCase = new CharacterRule(EnglishCharacterData.UpperCase);
    CharacterRule numbers = new CharacterRule(EnglishCharacterData.Digit);
    CharacterRule lowerCase = new CharacterRule(EnglishCharacterData.LowerCase);
    CharacterRule special = new CharacterRule(EnglishCharacterData.Special);

    PasswordGenerator passwordGenerator = new PasswordGenerator();

    return passwordGenerator.generatePassword(len, upperCase, lowerCase, special, numbers);
}
```

Comment: What does 'upper' and 'lower' mean? What do they have to do with a password?

Comment: upperCase and lowerCase characters to be included or not in the password to be generated

Comment: For reference: Don't bother users with these rules. If you force them to add a capital, they will capitalize the first letter. If you force a number, they will add a 1 at the end. If you force a symbol, they will add a !. You're annoying users and reducing security with this stuff. See NIST recommendation NIST SP 800-63. The correct rule is: 8 chars or more. Any character goes; no rules, and no pw expiry. Add a second factor such as TOTP.  No TOTP? Then it's insecure no matter how many rules you care to add.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that you can pass a list of the rules to the `generatePassword` function. So in this case you will first build a list with the rules and then pass it to the function.

Something like this:

```
private String passayPassGenerator(int len, boolean uppr, boolean lowr, boolean num, boolean spec) {
    CharacterRule upperCase = new CharacterRule(EnglishCharacterData.UpperCase);
    CharacterRule numbers = new CharacterRule(EnglishCharacterData.Digit);
    CharacterRule lowerCase = new CharacterRule(EnglishCharacterData.LowerCase);
    CharacterRule special = new CharacterRule(EnglishCharacterData.Special);

    List<CharacterRule> rules = new ArrayList<>();

    if (uppr) {
        rules.add(upperCase);
    }
    if (lowr) {
        rules.add(lowerCase);
    }
    if (num) {
        rules.add(numbers);
    }
    if (spec) {
        rules.add(special);
    }

    PasswordGenerator passwordGenerator = new PasswordGenerator();

    return passwordGenerator.generatePassword(len, rules);
}
```